# Storing and Displaying Data with Variables and an incrementing Loop

Tags: javascript

I wish to display on user input the varying amounts stored in the variables, but get them to increment accordingly after the first month using a loop to display 12 times.

Note: Ultimately the total amount will vary each month and the interest will adjust, but that is next on my list, I just want this to increment and display 12 times. I have also adjusted the code many times while asking this, with various loops and now i am getting a syntax error.

```js
var interest = prompt("Enter a percentage using a decimal Number...");
var interestRate = interest*100;
var startCash = 10000;
var total = startCash*interestRate/100+startCash;
var month = 1;

var Int = "Starting Money: £" + startCash;
var IntRate = "Interest Earned: " + interestRate + "%";
var Total = "Total Amount: £" + parseInt(total);
var Month = "This is Month: " + month;

var adjust = Int + IntRate + Total + Month;

if (interest != "")
{
 console.log(adjust);
 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. How to write a `for` loop?

Comment: I have been trying all night with various types of loops, Yet i just cannot get this to output how i need it too. It doesn't matter if its in a 'for' loop or even if it is in another loop, I just cant seem to get it to output "right"

Comment: Then please include the output you expect (this makes your question unambiguous) and the attempt that has failed (this helps people to explain the mistake you've been making).

Comment: @Tomalek, I did but someone edited the post before you edited it... How is one meant to get an answer if people continuosly edit it and then say they don't know what it is i'm trying to say. Stop Editing for the sake of it...

Comment: I edited none of your code. I fixed the indentation. (Compare [revision #3](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39303740/revisions#91f049d8-d3f1-42fb-93ec-19ede09e03bb), click "side-by-side markdown".) The other person did not edit your code, either.

Comment: @Tomalek The first guy who edited it, removed the wanted outcome. I have now re-edited it again and included the desired outcome again.

Comment: **I wish to display on user input the varying amounts stored in the variables, but get them to increment accordingly after the first month using a loop to display 12 times.** That is what i want my outcome to be... And yes my code has not changed on here because i am doing it locally or would you like to see a whole nights worth of poor code and errors too? And if there is errors in my code, then correct the code, I am trying to learn Javascript, So help or dont, but at least read the question for what i want the outcome to be